# How do i convert a date, stored as text with time, as "DD/MM/YYYY"

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, date, cell-format

Please can you help, I have a report, with a fixed output of "Dec 15 2022 17:00:00" as the date for each line of date; however, I need to add a column to change this data to "DD/MM/YYYY" so I can make a count of the number of "Today" and locate and report the oldest date. I am fine with the count of "today" and locating the oldest; however, I cannot get the date to convert! Please help!

Comment: Just as a side note, Excel is case insensitive when formatting dates to strings.  It doesn't affect the outcome in this specific case, but if you were to use `text([reference],"DDD MMM"` it would still output as "ddd mmm", i.e., `Thu Dec`; to get an uppercase output, wrap the `TEXT()` function with the `UPPER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution but this should work:

You can use this formula to convert your input into a date (it formats the contents of F1 so change the address as needed):

```
=DATE(MID(F1,7,5),MATCH(LEFT(F1,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),MID(F1,4,3))
```

If you actually need it in the format you have specified, you can wrap it in a TEXT with "dd/mm/yyyy" as a format like so:

```
=TEXT(DATE(MID(F1,7,5),MATCH(LEFT(F1,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),MID(F1,4,3)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as serial numbers, so the format is irrelevant. However, if your date is a **text string** and not a real date, you will need to convert it to a date. If you have Excel 365, one way to do that is to split the string; then return the date portion in DMY order with delimiters; then Excel can convert that to a "real date" (assuming you have an english version of Excel):
 *(you can format it however you want)*

```
=--TEXTJOIN("-",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),{2,1,3}))
```

If your date is a "real date" formatted to look as you show, then, to convert it:

```
=INT(A1)
```